# A simple filter on a table cell

Tags: html, filter, html-table, cell

I have a simple table that has only one column STATUS. I am trying to figure out a way to put in a filter on top of that cell.

```
<html>
<body>
  <input type="text" name="status" value=""/>
  <table>
    <tr><th>STATUS</th></tr>
    <tr><td>100</td></tr>
    <tr><td>200</td></tr>
    <tr><td>300</td></tr>
    <tr><td>101</td></tr>
    <tr><td>202</td></tr>
    <tr><td>400</td></tr>
    <tr><td>402</td></tr>
    <tr><td>500</td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have possibility to you JS Plugins, try [Dynatables](http://www.dynatable.com/). Simple for setting up and flexible.

Updated: If you need only JS function I think You need first of all initial html structure with select with options what you need. 
Listen events onChange on this $selectElement. Then it trigger change collection of your statuses regarding selected options in $selectElement(initail collection will be filtered by your state) use in this way $els = $.filter(// Condition) with condition to filter collection.
And last just render in:

```
$.each($els, function(el) {
   $tableBody.append(<td>$els</td>);
});
```

Comment: I just want a simple Javascript function